# Solve the phase state between two haplotype blocks using markov transition probabilities

Tags: python, performance, beginner, numpy, markov-chain

I have spent about more than a year in python, but I come from biology background. I should say I have got some understanding of for-loop and nested-for-loop to workout the solution to the problem I have had. But, I suppose that there are better and comprehensive way of solving problem.

Below is the code I wrote to solve the haplotype phase state between two haplotype blocks.

**Here is a short snipped of my data:**

```
chr  pos       ms01e_PI  ms01e_PG_al  ms02g_PI  ms02g_PG_al  ms03g_PI  ms03g_PG_al  ms04h_PI  ms04h_PG_al  ms05h_PI  ms05h_PG_al  ms06h_PI  ms06h_PG_al
2    15881764  4         C|T          6         C|T          7         T|T          7         T|T          7         C|T          7         C|T
2    15881767  4         C|C          6         T|C          7         C|C          7         C|C          7         T|C          7         C|C
2    15881989  4         C|C          6         A|C          7         C|C          7         C|C          7         A|T          7         A|C
2    15882091  4         G|T          6         G|T          7         T|A          7         A|A          7         A|T          7         A|C
2    15882451  4         C|T          4         T|C          7         T|T          7         T|T          7         C|T          7         C|A
2    15882454  4         C|T          4         T|C          7         T|T          7         T|T          7         C|T          7         C|T
2    15882493  4         C|T          4         T|C          7         T|T          7         T|T          7         C|T          7         C|T
2    15882505  4         A|T          4         T|A          7         T|T          7         T|T          7         A|C          7         A|T
```

**Problem:**

In the given data I want to solve the phase state of haplotype for the `sample ms02g`. The `suffix PI` represents the phased block (i.e all data within that block is phased).

For `sample ms02g` `C-T-A-G` is phased (PI level 6), so is `T-C-C-T`. Similarly data within PI level 4 is also phased. But, since the haplotype is broken in two levels, we don't know which phase from level-6 goes with which phase of level-4. [image: Phase to be solved - sample ms02g]

```
ms02g_PI  ms02g_PG_al
6         C|T
6         T|C
6         A|C
6         G|T
×——————————×—————> Break Point
4         T|C
4         T|C
4         T|C
4         T|A
```

Since, all other samples are completely phased I can run a markov-chain transition probabilities to solve the phase state. To the human eye/mind you can clearly see and say that left part of ms02g (level 6, i.e C-T-A-G is more likely to go with right block of level 4 C-C-C-A).

**Calculation:**

Step 01:

I prepare required haplotype configuration:

- The top haplotype-PI is `block01` and bottom is `block-02`.
- The left phased haplotype within each block is `Hap-A` and the right is `Hap-B`.

So, there are 2 haplotype configurations:

- Block01-HapA with Block02-HapA, so B01-HapB with B02-HapB
- Block01-HapA with Block02-HapB, so B01-HapB with B02-HapA

I count the number of transition for each nucleotide of PI-6 to each nucleotide of PI-4 for each haplotype configuration.
[image: possible transition from PI-6 to PI-4]

```
  Possible
  transitions    ms02g_PG_al
    │       ┌┬┬┬ C|T
    │       ││││ T|C
    │       ││││ A|C
    │       ││││ G|T
    └─────> ││││  ×—————> Break Point
            │││└ T|C
            ││└─ T|C
            │└── T|C
            └─── T|A
```

- and **multiply the transition probabilities** for first nucleotide in PI-6 to all nucleotides of PI-4. Then similarly multiply the transition probability for 2nd nucleotide of PI-6 to all nucleotides in PI-4.
- then I **sum the transition probabilities** from one level to another.

[image]

```
  Possible
  transitions    ms02g_PG_al
    │       ┌┬┬┬ C|T \
    │       ││││ T|C | Block 1
    │       ││││ A|C |
    │       ││││ G|T /
    └─────> ││││  ×—————> Break Point
            │││└ T|C \
            ││└─ T|C |
            │└── T|C | Block 2
            └─── T|A /
                 ↓ ↓
             Hap A Hap B
```

[image: calculating likelyhood]

```
  Block-1-Hap-A with Block-2-Hap-B    vs.    Block-1-Hap-A with Block-2-Hap-A

  C|C × C|C × C|C × A|C = 0.58612            T|C × T|C × T|C × T|C = 0.000244
+ C|T × C|T × C|T × A|T = 0.3164           + T|T × T|T × T|T × T|T = 0.00391
+ C|A × C|A × C|A × A|A = 0.482            + T|A × T|A × T|A × T|A = 0.0007716
+ C|G × C|G × C|G × A|G = 0.3164           + T|G × T|G × T|G × T|G = 0.00391
                          ———————                                    —————————
                    Avg = 0.42523                              Avg = 0.002207

        Likelyhood Ratio = 0.42523 / 0.002207 = 192.67
```

**I have the following working code with `python3`:**
I think the transition probs can be mostly optimized using numpy, or using a markov-chain package. But, I was not able to work them out in the way I desired. Also, it took me sometime to get to what I wanted to do.

Any suggestions with explanation. Thanks.

```
#!/home/bin/python
from __future__ import division

import collections
from itertools import product
from itertools import islice
import itertools
import csv
from pprint import pprint


''' function to count the number of transitions '''
def sum_Probs(pX_Y, pX):
    try:
        return float(pX_Y / pX)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0


with open("HaploBlock_Updated.txt", 'w') as f:

    ''' Write header (part 01): This is just a front part of the header. The rear part of the header is
    update dynamically depending upon the number of samples '''
    f.write('\t'.join(['chr', 'pos', 'ms02g_PI', 'ms02g_PG_al', '\n']))

    with open('HaploBlock_for_test-forHMMtoy02.txt') as Phased_Data:

        ''' Note: Create a dictionary to store required data. The Dict should contain information about
         two adjacent haplotype blocks that needs extending. In this example I want to extend the
         haplotypes for sample ms02g which has two blocks 6 and 4. So, I read the PI and PG value
         for this sample. Also, data should store with some unique keys. Some keys are: chr, pos,
         sample (PI, PG within sample), possible haplotypes ... etc .. '''


        Phased_Dict = csv.DictReader(Phased_Data, delimiter='\t')
        grouped = itertools.groupby(Phased_Dict, key=lambda x: x['ms02g_PI'])


        ''' Function to read the data as blocks (based on PI values of ms02g) at a time'''
        def accumulate(data):
            acc = collections.OrderedDict()
            for d in data:
                for k, v in d.items():
                    acc.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
            return acc


        ''' Store data as keys,values '''
        grouped_data = collections.OrderedDict()
        for k, g in grouped:
            grouped_data[k] = accumulate(g)


        ''' Clear memory '''
        del Phased_Dict
        del grouped

        ''' Iterate over two Hap Blocks at once. This is done to obtain all possible Haplotype
        configurations between two blocks. The (keys,values) for first block is represented as
        k1,v2 and for the later block as k2,v2. '''

        # Empty list for storing haplotypes from each block
        hap_Block1_A = [];
        hap_Block1_B = []
        hap_Block2_A = [];
        hap_Block2_B = []

        # Create empty list for possible haplotype configurations from above block
        hapB1A_hapB2A = []
        hapB1B_hapB2B = []

        ''' list of all available samples (index, value) '''
        sample_list = [('ms01e_PI', 'ms01e_PG_al'), ('ms02g_PI', 'ms02g_PG_al'),
                       ('ms03g_PI', 'ms03g_PG_al'), ('ms04h_PI', 'ms04h_PG_al'),
                       ('ms05h_PI', 'ms05h_PG_al'), ('ms06h_PI', 'ms06h_PG_al')]


        ''' read data from two consecutive blocks at a time '''
        for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in zip(grouped_data.items(), islice(grouped_data.items(), 1, None)):
            ''' skip if one of the keys has no values'''
            if k1 == '.' or k2 == '.':
                continue


            ''' iterate over the first Haplotype Block, i.e the k1 block.
            The nucleotides in the left of the phased SNPs are called Block01-haplotype-A,
            and similarly on the right as Block01-haplotype-B. '''
            hap_Block1_A = [x.split('|')[0] for x in v1['ms02g_PG_al']] # the left haplotype of Block01
            hap_Block1_B = [x.split('|')[1] for x in v1['ms02g_PG_al']]


            ''' iterate over the second Haplotype Block,
            i.e the k2 block '''
            hap_Block2_A = [x.split('|')[0] for x in v2['ms02g_PG_al']]
            hap_Block2_B = [x.split('|')[1] for x in v2['ms02g_PG_al']]



            ''' Now, we have to start to solve the possible haplotype configuration.
            Possible haplotype Configurations will be, Either :
            1) Block01-haplotype-A phased with Block02-haplotype-A,
                creating -> hapB1A-hapB2A, hapB1B-hapB2B
            Or,
            2) Block01-haplotype-A phased with Block02-haplotype-B
                creating -> hapB1A-hapB2B, hapB1B-hapB2A '''

            ''' First possible configuration '''
            hapB1A_hapB2A = [hap_Block1_A, hap_Block2_A]
            hapB1B_hapB2B = [hap_Block1_B, hap_Block2_B]

            ''' Second Possible Configuration '''
            hapB1A_hapB2B = [hap_Block1_A, hap_Block2_B]
            hapB1B_hapB2A = [hap_Block1_B, hap_Block2_A]


            print('\nStarting MarkovChains')
            ''' Now, start preping the first order markov transition matrix
             for the observed haplotypes between two blocks.'''


            ''' To store the sum-values of the product of the transition probabilities.
            These sum are added as the product-of-transition is retured by nested for-loop;
            from "for m in range(....)" '''

            Sum_Of_Product_of_Transition_probabilities_hapB1A_hapB2A = \
                sumOf_PT_hapB1A_B2A = 0
            Sum_Of_Product_of_Transition_probabilities_hapB1B_hapB2B = \
                sumOf_PT_hapB1B_B2B = 0

            Sum_Of_Product_of_Transition_probabilities_hapB1A_hapB2B = \
                sumOf_PT_hapB1A_B2B = 0
            Sum_Of_Product_of_Transition_probabilities_hapB1B_hapB2A = \
                sumOf_PT_hapB1B_B2A = 0


            for n in range(len(v1['ms02g_PI'])):  # n-ranges from block01

                ''' Set the probabilities of each nucleotides at Zero. They are updated for each level
                 of "n" after reading the number of each nucleotides at that position. '''
                pA = 0; pT = 0; pG = 0; pC = 0
                # nucleotide_prob = [0., 0., 0., 0.] # or store as numpy matrix

                # Also storing these values as Dict
                # probably can be improved
                nucleotide_prob_dict = {'A': 0, 'T': 0, 'G': 0, 'C': 0}
                print('prob as Dict: ', nucleotide_prob_dict)


                ''' for storing the product-values of the transition probabilities.
                These are updated for each level of "n" paired with each level of "m". '''
                product_of_transition_Probs_hapB1AB2A = POTP_hapB1AB2A = 1
                product_of_transition_Probs_hapB1BB2B = POTP_hapB1BB2B = 1

                product_of_transition_Probs_hapB1AB2B = POTP_hapB1AB2B = 1
                product_of_transition_Probs_hapB1BB2A = POTP_hapB1BB2A = 1



                ''' Now, we read each level of "m" to compute the transition from each level of "n"
                to each level of "m". '''
                for m in range(len(v2['ms02g_PI'])): # m-ranges from block02
                    # transition for each level of 0-to-n level of V1 to 0-to-m level of V2
                    ''' set transition probabilities at Zero for each possible transition '''
                    pA_A = 0; pA_T = 0; pA_G = 0; pA_C = 0
                    pT_A = 0; pT_T = 0; pT_G = 0; pT_C = 0
                    pG_A = 0; pG_T = 0; pG_G = 0; pG_C = 0
                    pC_A = 0; pC_T = 0; pC_G = 0; pC_C = 0

                    ''' Also, creating an empty dictionary to store transition probabilities
                    - probably upgrade using numpy '''
                    transition_prob_dict = {'A_A' : 0, 'A_T' : 0, 'A_G' : 0, 'A_C' : 0,
                    'T_A' : 0, 'T_T' : 0, 'T_G' : 0, 'T_C' : 0,
                    'G_A' : 0, 'G_T' : 0, 'G_G' : 0, 'G_C' : 0,
                    'C_A' : 0, 'C_T' : 0, 'C_G' : 0, 'C_C' : 0}


                    ''' Now, loop through each sample to compute initial probs and transition probs '''
                    for x, y in sample_list:
                        print('sample x and y:', x,y)


                        ''' Update nucleotide probability for this site
                        - only calculated from v1 and only once for each parse/iteration '''
                        if m == 0:
                            pA += (v1[y][n].count('A'))
                            pT += (v1[y][n].count('T'))
                            pG += (v1[y][n].count('G'))
                            pC += (v1[y][n].count('C'))

                            nucleotide_prob_dict['A'] = pA
                            nucleotide_prob_dict['T'] = pT
                            nucleotide_prob_dict['G'] = pG
                            nucleotide_prob_dict['C'] = pC

                        nucleotide_prob = [pA, pT, pG, pC]


                        ''' Now, update transition matrix '''
                        nucl_B1 = (v1[y][n]).split('|')  # nucleotides at Block01
                        nucl_B2 = (v2[y][m]).split('|')  # nucleotides at Block02


                        ''' create possible haplotype configurations between "n" and "m".
                         If the index (PI value) are same we create zip, if index (PI value) are
                         different we create product. '''

                        HapConfig = []  # create empty list

                        if v1[x][n] == v2[x][m]:
                            ziped_nuclB1B2 = [(x + '_' + y) for (x,y) in zip(nucl_B1, nucl_B2)]
                            HapConfig = ziped_nuclB1B2

                            ''' Move this counting function else where '''
                            pA_A += (HapConfig.count('A_A'))  # (v1[y][0].count('A'))/8
                            pA_T += (HapConfig.count('A_T'))
                            pA_G += (HapConfig.count('A_G'))
                            pA_C += (HapConfig.count('A_C'))

                            pT_A += (HapConfig.count('T_A'))  # (v1[y][0].count('A'))/8
                            pT_T += (HapConfig.count('T_T'))
                            pT_G += (HapConfig.count('T_G'))
                            pT_C += (HapConfig.count('T_C'))

                            pG_A += (HapConfig.count('G_A'))  # (v1[y][0].count('A'))/8
                            pG_T += (HapConfig.count('G_T'))
                            pG_G += (HapConfig.count('G_G'))
                            pG_C += (HapConfig.count('G_C'))

                            pC_A += (HapConfig.count('C_A'))
                            pC_T += (HapConfig.count('C_T'))
                            pC_G += (HapConfig.count('C_G'))
                            pC_C += (HapConfig.count('C_C'))


                        if v1[x][n] != v2[x][m]:
                            prod_nuclB1B2 = [(x + '_' + y) for (x,y) in product(nucl_B1, nucl_B2)]
                            HapConfig = prod_nuclB1B2
                            print('prod NuclB1B2: ', prod_nuclB1B2)

                            pA_A += (HapConfig.count('A_A'))/2
                            pA_T += (HapConfig.count('A_T'))/2
                            pA_G += (HapConfig.count('A_G'))/2
                            pA_C += (HapConfig.count('A_C'))/2

                            pT_A += (HapConfig.count('T_A'))/2
                            pT_T += (HapConfig.count('T_T'))/2
                            pT_G += (HapConfig.count('T_G'))/2
                            pT_C += (HapConfig.count('T_C'))/2

                            pG_A += (HapConfig.count('G_A'))/2
                            pG_T += (HapConfig.count('G_T'))/2
                            pG_G += (HapConfig.count('G_G'))/2
                            pG_C += (HapConfig.count('G_C'))/2

                            pC_A += (HapConfig.count('C_A'))/2
                            pC_T += (HapConfig.count('C_T'))/2
                            pC_G += (HapConfig.count('C_G'))/2
                            pC_C += (HapConfig.count('C_C'))/2


                    ''' Now, compute nucleotide and transition probabilities for each nucleotide
                    from each 0-n to 0-m at each sample. This updates the transition matrix in
                    each loop. **Note: At the end this transition probabilities should sum to 1 '''

                    ''' Storing nucleotide probabilities '''
                    nucleotide_prob = [pA, pT, pG, pC]

                    ''' Storing transition probability as dict'''
                    transition_prob_dict['A_A'] = sum_Probs(pA_A,pA)
                    transition_prob_dict['A_T'] = sum_Probs(pA_T,pA)
                    transition_prob_dict['A_G'] = sum_Probs(pA_G,pA)
                    transition_prob_dict['A_C'] = sum_Probs(pA_C,pA)

                    transition_prob_dict['T_A'] = sum_Probs(pT_A,pT)
                    transition_prob_dict['T_T'] = sum_Probs(pT_T,pT)
                    transition_prob_dict['T_G'] = sum_Probs(pT_G,pT)
                    transition_prob_dict['T_C'] = sum_Probs(pT_C,pT)

                    transition_prob_dict['G_A'] = sum_Probs(pG_A,pG)
                    transition_prob_dict['G_T'] = sum_Probs(pG_T,pG)
                    transition_prob_dict['G_G'] = sum_Probs(pG_G,pG)
                    transition_prob_dict['G_C'] = sum_Probs(pG_C,pG)

                    transition_prob_dict['C_A'] = sum_Probs(pC_A,pC)
                    transition_prob_dict['C_T'] = sum_Probs(pC_T,pC)
                    transition_prob_dict['C_G'] = sum_Probs(pC_G,pC)
                    transition_prob_dict['C_C'] = sum_Probs(pC_C,pC)


                    '''Now, we start solving the haplotype configurations after we have the
                      required data (nucleotide and transition probabilities).
                    Calculate joint probability for each haplotype configuration.
                    Step 01: We calculate the product of the transition from one level
                    of "n" to several levels of "m". '''

                    ''' finding possible configuration between "n" and "m". '''
                    hapB1A_hapB2A_transition = hapB1A_hapB2A[0][n] + '_' + hapB1A_hapB2A[1][m]
                    hapB1B_hapB2B_transition = hapB1B_hapB2B[0][n] + '_' + hapB1B_hapB2B[1][m]

                    hapB1A_hapB2B_transition = hapB1A_hapB2B[0][n] + '_' + hapB1A_hapB2B[1][m]
                    hapB1B_hapB2A_transition = hapB1B_hapB2A[0][n] + '_' + hapB1B_hapB2A[1][m]


                    ''' computing the products of transition probabilities on the for loop '''
                    POTP_hapB1AB2A *= transition_prob_dict[hapB1A_hapB2A_transition]
                    POTP_hapB1BB2B *= transition_prob_dict[hapB1B_hapB2B_transition]

                    POTP_hapB1AB2B *= transition_prob_dict[hapB1A_hapB2B_transition]
                    POTP_hapB1BB2A *= transition_prob_dict[hapB1B_hapB2A_transition]


                ''' Step 02: sum of the product of the transition probabilities '''
                sumOf_PT_hapB1A_B2A += POTP_hapB1AB2A
                sumOf_PT_hapB1B_B2B += POTP_hapB1BB2B

                sumOf_PT_hapB1A_B2B += POTP_hapB1AB2B
                sumOf_PT_hapB1B_B2A += POTP_hapB1BB2A


            ''' Step 03: Now, computing the likely hood of each haplotype configuration '''
            print('computing likelyhood:')

            likelyhood_hapB1A_with_B2A_Vs_B2B = LH_hapB1AwB2AvsB2B = \
                sumOf_PT_hapB1A_B2A / sumOf_PT_hapB1A_B2B
            likelyhood_hapB1B_with_B2B_Vs_B2A = LH_hapB1BwB2BvsB2A = \
                sumOf_PT_hapB1B_B2B / sumOf_PT_hapB1B_B2A

            likelyhood_hapB1A_with_B2B_Vs_B2A = LH_hapB1AwB2BvsB2A = \
                sumOf_PT_hapB1A_B2B / sumOf_PT_hapB1A_B2A
            likelyhood_hapB1B_with_B2A_Vs_B2B = LH_hapB1BwB2AvsB2B = \
                sumOf_PT_hapB1B_B2A / sumOf_PT_hapB1B_B2B


            print('\nlikely hood Values: B1A with B2A vs. B2B, B1B with B2B vs. B2A')
            print(LH_hapB1AwB2AvsB2B, LH_hapB1BwB2BvsB2A)

            print('\nlikely hood Values: B1A with B2B vs. B2A, B1B with B2A vs. B2B')
            print(LH_hapB1AwB2BvsB2A, LH_hapB1BwB2AvsB2B)


            ''' Update the phase state of the block based on evidence '''
            if (LH_hapB1AwB2AvsB2B + LH_hapB1BwB2BvsB2A) > \
                4*(LH_hapB1AwB2BvsB2A + LH_hapB1BwB2AvsB2B):
                print('Block-1_A is phased with Block-2_A')

                for x in range(len(v1['ms02g_PI'])):
                    PI_value = v1['ms02g_PI'][x]
                    # Note: so, we trasfer the PI value from ealier block to next block

                    f.write('\t'.join([v1['chr'][x], v1['pos'][x], v1['ms02g_PI'][x],
                                       hapB1A_hapB2A[0][x] + '|' + hapB1B_hapB2B[0][x], '\n']))

                for x in range(len(v2['ms02g_PI'])):
                    f.write('\t'.join([v2['chr'][x], v2['pos'][x], PI_value,
                                       hapB1A_hapB2A[1][x] + '|' + hapB1B_hapB2B[1][x], '\n']))

            elif (LH_hapB1AwB2AvsB2B + LH_hapB1BwB2BvsB2A) < \
                4 * (LH_hapB1AwB2BvsB2A + LH_hapB1BwB2AvsB2B):
                print('Block-1_A is phased with Block-2_B')

                for x in range(len(v1['ms02g_PI'])):
                    PI_value = v1['ms02g_PI'][x]
                    # Note: so, we trasfer the PI value from ealier block to next block...
                        # but, the phase position are reversed

                    f.write('\t'.join([v1['chr'][x], v1['pos'][x], v1['ms02g_PI'][x],
                                       hapB1A_hapB2A[0][x] + '|' + hapB1B_hapB2B[0][x], '\n']))

                for x in range(len(v2['ms02g_PI'])):
                    f.write('\t'.join([v2['chr'][x], v2['pos'][x], PI_value,
                                       hapB1B_hapB2B[1][x] + '|' + hapB1A_hapB2A[1][x], '\n']))


            else:
                print('cannot solve the phase state with confidence - sorry ')
                for x in range(len(v1['ms02g_PI'])):
                    f.write('\t'.join([v1['chr'][x], v1['pos'][x], v1['ms02g_PI'][x],
                                   hapB1A_hapB2A[0][x] + '|' + hapB1B_hapB2B[0][x], '\n']))

                for x in range(len(v2['ms02g_PI'])):
                    f.write('\t'.join([v2['chr'][x], v2['pos'][x], v2['ms02g_PI'][x],
                                       hapB1A_hapB2A[1][x] + '|' + hapB1B_hapB2B[1][x], '\n']))
```

Comment: Nice question! Thorough explanations and I like the handwritten diagrams. I hope you get some good answers.

Comment: I tried to improve readability of the table by adding spaces and converted some images into text. Feel free to revert if you think this does more harm than good.

Comment: Also in the last image, you wrote "Block-1-Hap-A with Block-2-Hap-B" vs. "Block-1-Hap-A with Block-2-Hap-A" but as I read the data below, it's the other way round ("2B with 1A" and "2A with 1A"). Does it matter in any way?

Comment: @mathias: that's true. I just happened to flip the position of haplotypes, when trying to test so three conditions. Also, thanks a lot for improving the format of the question.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger: it should not matter much. I have not received any answers to this question. How should I gather more attention?

Comment: Considering the amount of upvotes, this question is deemed interesting. It's just a difficult one, give the reviewers some time :)

Comment: I plan to answer this; there is some good stuff here and also some low-hanging fruit to improve. I would be interested in a longer dataset to run this on. This holds especially given you have the `performance` tag, which is generally very dependent on the actual data.

Comment: @Veedrac: thanks for coming forward.  Would it be ok if I shared the large file via Dropbox. But for now improvement based on this snippet should suffice.

Comment: @everestial007 That would be fine.

Comment: @Veedrac and others: Any suggestions so far?

Comment: @everestial007 It's taking a while because it's longer than expected and I've put less time aside for it than I thought I would. I'll see if I have something for the weekend, but it'll be done when it's done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before we get to the interesting stuff, we should handle some stylistic niggles. Note that [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is a de-facto style for Python code. First, imports should be sorted

```
import collections
import csv
import itertools
from itertools import islice
from itertools import product
from pprint import pprint
```

You only use `collections` for `OrderedDict`, so import that directly.

Names should be either `snake_case`, for functions and variables, or `UpperCamelCase` for classes. This means

```
sum_probs → sum_Probs
pX_Y → px_y
pX → px
Phased_Data → phased_data
Phased_Dict → phased_dict
hap_Block1_A → hap_block1_a
hap_Block1_B → hap_block1_b
hap_Block2_A → hap_block2_a
hap_Block2_B → hap_block2_b
hapB1A_hapB2A → hapb1a_hapb2a
hapB1B_hapB2B → hapb1b_hapb2b
hapB1A_hapB2B → hapb1a_hapb2b
hapB1B_hapB2A → hapb1b_hapb2a
Sum_Of_Product_of_Transition_probabilities_hapB1A_hapB2A → sum_of_product_of_transition_probabilities_hapb1a_hapb2a
sumOf_PT_hapB1A_B2A → sum_of_pt_hapb1a_b2a
Sum_Of_Product_of_Transition_probabilities_hapB1B_hapB2B → sum_of_product_of_transition_probabilities_hapb1b_hapb2b
sumOf_PT_hapB1B_B2B → sum_of_pt_hapb1b_b2b
Sum_Of_Product_of_Transition_probabilities_hapB1A_hapB2B → sum_of_product_of_transition_probabilities_hapb1a_hapb2b
sumOf_PT_hapB1A_B2B → sum_of_pt_hapb1a_b2b
Sum_Of_Product_of_Transition_probabilities_hapB1B_hapB2A → sum_of_product_of_transition_probabilities_hapb1b_hapb2a
sumOf_PT_hapB1B_B2A → sum_of_pt_hapb1b_b2a
pA → pa
pT → pt
pG → pg
pC → pc
product_of_transition_Probs_hapB1AB2A → product_of_transition_probs_hapb1ab2a
POTP_hapB1AB2A → potp_hapb1ab2a
product_of_transition_Probs_hapB1BB2B → product_of_transition_probs_hapb1bb2b
POTP_hapB1BB2B → potp_hapb1bb2b
product_of_transition_Probs_hapB1AB2B → product_of_transition_probs_hapb1ab2b
POTP_hapB1AB2B → potp_hapb1ab2b
product_of_transition_Probs_hapB1BB2A → product_of_transition_probs_hapb1bb2a
POTP_hapB1BB2A → potp_hapb1bb2a
pA_A → pa_a
pA_T → pa_t
pA_G → pa_g
pA_C → pa_c
pT_A → pt_a
pT_T → pt_t
pT_G → pt_g
pT_C → pt_c
pG_A → pg_a
pG_T → pg_t
pG_G → pg_g
pG_C → pg_c
pC_A → pc_a
pC_T → pc_t
pC_G → pc_g
pC_C → pc_c
nucl_B1 → nucl_b1
nucl_B2 → nucl_b2
HapConfig → hap_config
likelyhood_hapB1A_with_B2A_Vs_B2B → likelyhood_hapb1a_with_b2a_vs_b2b
LH_hapB1AwB2AvsB2B → lh_hapb1awb2avsb2b
likelyhood_hapB1B_with_B2B_Vs_B2A → likelyhood_hapb1b_with_b2b_vs_b2a
LH_hapB1BwB2BvsB2A → lh_hapb1bwb2bvsb2a
likelyhood_hapB1A_with_B2B_Vs_B2A → likelyhood_hapb1a_with_b2b_vs_b2a
LH_hapB1AwB2BvsB2A → lh_hapb1awb2bvsb2a
likelyhood_hapB1B_with_B2A_Vs_B2B → likelyhood_hapb1b_with_b2a_vs_b2b
LH_hapB1BwB2AvsB2B → lh_hapb1bwb2avsb2b
```

Some notes I will get back to later:

- Consistency is important. Don't write `hapB1A_hapB2A` in one place, `hapB1A_B2A` in another and `hapB1AB2A` in another.
- Don't use variables as comments where comments would work better.
- There is a lot of *structure* here, like `p[ATGC]_[ATGC]` that suggests working at a higher level would save a lot of effort.

But enough of this for now.

First function, `sum_probs`.

```
''' function to count the number of transitions '''
def sum_probs(px_y, px):
    try:
        return float(px_y / px)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0
```

To be frank, this makes no sense.

- You very sensibly added `from __future__ import division`, so the `float` case is useless.
- You catch `ZeroDivisionError` and return 0, which is not explained or warned about.
- Your docstring is misplaced and does not match [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) guidelines.
- Your docstring says you "count the number of transitions", but you do no counting, rather a single division.

Let's fix the easy issues and move it to neighbor the only place it's used so we can revisit it at a more appropriate time.

```
def sum_probs(px_y, px):
    """Return the number of transitions."""
    try:
        return px_y / px
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

''' Storing transition probability as dict'''
transition_prob_dict['A_A'] = sum_probs(pa_a,pa)
...
```

We then open with a file open

```
with open("HaploBlock_Updated.txt", 'w') as f:

    ''' Write header (part 01): This is just a front part of the header. The rear part of the header is
    update dynamically depending upon the number of samples '''
    f.write('\t'.join(['chr', 'pos', 'ms02g_PI', 'ms02g_PG_al', '\n']))
```

First of all, +1 for using `with`. However,

- Almost all Python code should be encapsulated inside functions, and doing complex logic in the global scope is highly disadvised.
- You don't use `f` yet, so it is best to only open it later. Eventually we'd like it to only wrap the part that actually cares about it.
- Using strings as multiline comments is not idiomatic and rather disadvised.

You then repeat this with

```
with open('HaploBlock_for_test-forHMMtoy02.txt') as phased_data:

    ''' Note: Create a dictionary to store required data. The Dict should contain information about
     two adjacent haplotype blocks that needs extending. In this example I want to extend the
     haplotypes for sample ms02g which has two blocks 6 and 4. So, I read the PI and PG value
     for this sample. Also, data should store with some unique keys. Some keys are: chr, pos,
     sample (PI, PG within sample), possible haplotypes ... etc .. '''

    // lots more logic
```

The file should be closed as soon as you are finished with it, and the comment should be reformatted.

```
# Create a dictionary to store required data.
#
# The Dict should contain information about two adjacent
# haplotype blocks that needs extending. In this example
# I want to extend the haplotypes for sample ms02g, which
# has two blocks, 6 and 4, so I read the PI and PG value
# for this sample.
#
# Also, data should be stored with unique keys.
# Some keys are: chr, pos, sample (PI, PG within sample),
# possible haplotypes, etc.
with open('HaploBlock_for_test-forHMMtoy02.txt') as phased_data:
    // logic that uses phased_data

// lots more logic
```

I am not going to mention using strings as comments again, but you do need to fix this everywhere. Remember that this does not apply to docstrings, where you should follow [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

Inside the now-first block, we have an `accumulate` function

```
''' Function to read the data as blocks (based on PI values of ms02g) at a time'''
def accumulate(data):
    acc = OrderedDict()
    for d in data:
        for k, v in d.items():
            acc.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
    return acc
```

Let's quickly work on that docstring. First of all, note that it's in the wrong place and not in the right voice.

```
def accumulate(data):
    """Read the data as blocks (based on PI values of ms02g) at a time."""
    ...
```

Secondly, the function is *generic*. It does not read data. It does not care about `ms02g`. IT just groups data in a certain manner. That is what it does, so that is what it should say it does. Its name should reflect this.

```
def merge_ordereddicts(odicts):
    """Merge ordered dictionaries, mapping each key to
    lists of all values mapped to in order of occurence."""
    ...
```

I do not believe there is any reason for these dictionaries to actually be ordered, so I would abandon that. I would also prefer short names to single letter variables.

```
def merge_dicts(dicts):
    """Merge dictionaries, mapping each key to lists
    of all values mapped to in order of occurence."""

    merged = {}
    for dict_ in dicts:
        for key, val in dict_.items():
            merged.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
    return merged
```

You then write

```
''' Store data as keys,values '''
grouped_data = OrderedDict()
for k, g in grouped:
    grouped_data[k] = merge_dicts(g)
```

which would be nicer as a comprehension

```
grouped_data = OrderedDict((k, merge_dicts(g)) for k, g in grouped)
```

You finished off with

```
del phased_dict
del grouped
```

An experienced Python programmer would probably be very averse to those lines; deleting variables should be done very sparingly. But in this context it's actually good; you have global data and you're clearing the mess up after yourself. The reason experienced programmers don't do this very much is because they know to *encapsulate* logic like this instead. The end result looks something like

```
def merge_dicts(dicts):
    """Merge dictionaries, mapping each key to lists
    of all values mapped to in order of occurence."""

    merged = {}
    for dict_ in dicts:
        for key, val in dict_.items():
            merged.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
    return merged

def parse_phased_data(file):
    """Parse input into OrderedDict keyed by ms02g_PI.

    The result contains information about two adjacent
    haplotype blocks that needs extending.

    Data should be stored with unique keys.
    Some keys are: chr, pos, sample (PI, PG within sample),
    possible haplotypes, etc."""

    phased_dict = csv.DictReader(phased_data, delimiter='\t')
    grouped = itertools.groupby(phased_dict, key=lambda x: x['ms02g_PI'])
    return OrderedDict((k, merge_dicts(g)) for k, g in grouped)

with open('HaploBlock_for_test-forHMMtoy02.txt') as phased_data:
    grouped_data = parse_phased_data(phased_data)
```

I don't entirely understand your docstrings, so I may have mangled them a little. The final `with` and assignment itself will eventually be moved into another function.

Next,

```
hap_block1_a = [];
hap_block1_b = []
hap_block2_a = [];
hap_block2_b = []

# Create empty list for possible haplotype configurations from above block
hapb1a_hapb2a = []
hapb1b_hapb2b = []
```

What;s with those semicolons? More importantly, these assigned values are never used since they always get assigned ahead of time, so they can only hide bugs. Remove them entirely!

You then

```
# list of all available samples (index, value)
sample_list = [('ms01e_PI', 'ms01e_PG_al'), ('ms02g_PI', 'ms02g_PG_al'),
               ('ms03g_PI', 'ms03g_PG_al'), ('ms04h_PI', 'ms04h_PG_al'),
               ('ms05h_PI', 'ms05h_PG_al'), ('ms06h_PI', 'ms06h_PG_al')]
```

but only use this way down on what is for me now line 146,

```
for x, y in sample_list:
    ...
```

It is best to just move it there, though you should use a tuple instead because, being immutable, those can be built once and then reused.

```
# Loop through each sample to compute initial probs and transition probs.
sample_list = (('ms01e_PI', 'ms01e_PG_al'), ('ms02g_PI', 'ms02g_PG_al'),
               ('ms03g_PI', 'ms03g_PG_al'), ('ms04h_PI', 'ms04h_PG_al'),
               ('ms05h_PI', 'ms05h_PG_al'), ('ms06h_PI', 'ms06h_PG_al'))

for x, y in sample_list:
    ...
```

Then you go straight to the loop,

```
# Iterate over two Hap Blocks at once. This is done to obtain all possible Haplotype
# configurations between two blocks. The (keys,values) for first block is represented as
# k1,v2 and for the later block as k2,v2.
for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in zip(grouped_data.items(), islice(grouped_data.items(), 1, None)):
    # Skip if one of the keys has no values
    if k1 == '.' or k2 == '.':
        continue
```

Because all the shared variables have been removed, it is now obvious that each iteration is *stateless* except for the file being written into. This means we can move the entire contents of the loop into a function, though it is cleaner to keep the first `if` outside.

```
def some_function(f, k1, v1, k2, v2):
    """..."""

with open("HaploBlock_Updated.txt", 'w') as f:
    # Write header (part 01):
    # This is just a front part of the header.
    # The rear part of the header is date dynamically depending upon the number of samples.
    f.write('\t'.join(['chr', 'pos', 'ms02g_PI', 'ms02g_PG_al', '\n']))

    # Iterate over two Hap Blocks at once. This is done to obtain all possible Haplotype
    # configurations between two blocks. The (keys,values) for first block is represented as
    # k1,v2 and for the later block as k2,v2.
    for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in zip(grouped_data.items(), islice(grouped_data.items(), 1, None)):
        # Skip if one of the keys has no values
        if k1 == '.' or k2 == '.':
            continue

        some_function(f, k1, v1, k2, v2)
```

Obviously this needs a better name than `some_function(f, k1, v1, k2, v2)`, and better documentation than just an ellipsis. I will leave that as a task for you to figure out.

Next we have

```
# Iterate over the first Haplotype Block, i.e the k1 block.
# The nucleotides in the left of the phased SNPs are called Block01-haplotype-A,
# and similarly on the right as Block01-haplotype-B.
hap_block1_a = [x.split('|')[0] for x in v1['ms02g_PG_al']] # the left haplotype of Block01
hap_block1_b = [x.split('|')[1] for x in v1['ms02g_PG_al']]

# Iterate over the second Haplotype Block,
# i.e the k2 block
hap_block2_a = [x.split('|')[0] for x in v2['ms02g_PG_al']]
hap_block2_b = [x.split('|')[1] for x in v2['ms02g_PG_al']]

# Now, we have to start to solve the possible haplotype configuration.
# Possible haplotype configurations are either
#
# 1. Block01-haplotype-A phased with Block02-haplotype-A,
#     creating -> hapB1A-hapB2A, hapB1B-hapB2B
#
# 2. Block01-haplotype-A phased with Block02-haplotype-B
#     creating -> hapB1A-hapB2B, hapB1B-hapB2A

# First possible configuration
hapb1a_hapb2a = [hap_block1_a, hap_block2_a]
hapb1b_hapb2b = [hap_block1_b, hap_block2_b]

# Secondd possible configuration
hapb1a_hapb2b = [hap_block1_a, hap_block2_b]
hapb1b_hapb2a = [hap_block1_b, hap_block2_a]
```

Note that the `hap_block` variables are only ever used inside this snippet, and all take the form

```
[x.split('|')[X] for x in vY['ms02g_PG_al']]
```

for `X` and `Y`. So let's make that a function

```
# Iterate over the Haplotype Block, i.e the k1 block.
# The nucleotides in the left of the phased SNPs are called Block01-haplotype-A,
# and similarly on the right as Block01-haplotype-B.
def hap_block(side, val):
    return [x.split('|')[side] for x in val['ms02g_PG_al']]

# Now, we have to start to solve the possible haplotype configuration.
# Possible haplotype configurations are either:

# 1. Block01-haplotype-A phased with Block02-haplotype-A,
#     creating -> hapB1A-hapB2A, hapB1B-hapB2B
hapb1a_hapb2a = [hap_block(0, v1), hap_block(0, v2)]
hapb1b_hapb2b = [hap_block(1, v1), hap_block(1, v2)]

# 2. Block01-haplotype-A phased with Block02-haplotype-B
#     creating -> hapB1A-hapB2B, hapB1B-hapB2A
hapb1a_hapb2b = [hap_block(0, v1), hap_block(1, v2)]
hapb1b_hapb2a = [hap_block(1, v1), hap_block(0, v2)]
```

Even better, produce a table.

```
hap_b1_to_b2 = {
    ('a', 'a'): [hap_block(0, v1), hap_block(0, v2)],
    ('a', 'b'): [hap_block(0, v1), hap_block(1, v2)],
    ('b', 'a'): [hap_block(1, v1), hap_block(0, v2)],
    ('b', 'b'): [hap_block(1, v1), hap_block(1, v2)],
}
```

But not that this is only ever used as

```
hap_b1_to_b2[idx][0][n] + '_' + hap_b1_to_b2[idx][1][m]
```

As a small nit, next you

```
print('\nStarting MarkovChains')
```

which I would find nicer as two separate print statements.

```
print()
print('Starting MarkovChains')
```

You write

```
sum_of_product_of_transition_probabilities_hapb1a_hapb2a = \
    sumof_pt_hapb1a_b2a = 0
sum_of_product_of_transition_probabilities_hapb1b_hapb2b = \
    sumof_pt_hapb1b_b2b = 0

sum_of_product_of_transition_probabilities_hapb1a_hapb2b = \
    sumof_pt_hapb1a_b2b = 0
sum_of_product_of_transition_probabilities_hapb1b_hapb2a = \
    sumof_pt_hapb1b_b2a = 0
```

This is not good; don't use dead variables as comments. There are other places you do this; fix them all.

Secondly, this once again implies you should be using some kind of higher-level container.

```
transition_prob_sums = {
    ('a', 'a'): 0,
    ('a', 'b'): 0,
    ('b', 'a'): 0,
    ('b', 'b'): 0,
}
```

You then start a loop

```
for n in range(len(v1['ms02g_PI'])):  # n-ranges from block01
```

Idiomatically, this would look more like

```
for n, _ in enumerate(v1['ms02g_PI']):
```

Inside the first level you write

```
# set the probabilities of each nucleotides at zero. they are updated for each level
# of "n" after reading the number of each nucleotides at that position.
pa = 0; pt = 0; pg = 0; pc = 0
# nucleotide_prob = [0., 0., 0., 0.] # or store as numpy matrix

# also storing these values as dict
# probably can be improved
nucleotide_prob_dict = {'A': 0, 'T': 0, 'G': 0, 'C': 0}
print('prob as dict: ', nucleotide_prob_dict)


# for storing the product-values of the transition probabilities.
# these are updated for each level of "n" paired with each level of "m".
potp_hapb1ab2a = 1
potp_hapb1bb2b = 1

potp_hapb1ab2b = 1
potp_hapb1bb2a = 1

# now, we read each level of "m" to compute the transition from each level of "n"
# to each level of "m".
for m in range(len(v2['ms02g_PI'])): # m-ranges from block02
    # .. inner loop ..

# step 02: sum of the product of the transition probabilities
transition_prob_sums['a','a'] += potp_hapb1ab2a
transition_prob_sums['b','b'] += potp_hapb1bb2b

transition_prob_sums['a','b'] += potp_hapb1ab2b
transition_prob_sums['b','a'] += potp_hapb1bb2a
```

You clearly have some idea with introducing `nucleotide_prob_dict`, but you fail to capitalize on it since you never do anything with the type. Let's try another approach, using *only* the dictionary

```
# Probabilities of each nucleotides start at zero,
# and are updated each outer iteration after reading
# the number of each nucleotide at that position.
nucleotide_probs = {'A': 0, 'T': 0, 'G': 0, 'C': 0}
print('prob as dict: ', nucleotide_probs)

# The product-values of the transition probabilities,
# updated each inner iteration.
prod_transition_probs = {
    ('a', 'a'): 1,
    ('a', 'b'): 1,
    ('b', 'a'): 1,
    ('b', 'b'): 1,
}
```

We'll come to the run-on effects of doing this later. We enter the inner loop and get another encounter,

```
pa_a = 0; pa_t = 0; pa_g = 0; pa_c = 0
pt_a = 0; pt_t = 0; pt_g = 0; pt_c = 0
pg_a = 0; pg_t = 0; pg_g = 0; pg_c = 0
pc_a = 0; pc_t = 0; pc_g = 0; pc_c = 0
```

which we can rewrite

```
transition_probs = {
    ('A','A'): 0, ('A','T'): 0, ('A','G'): 0, ('A','C'): 0,
    ('T','A'): 0, ('T','T'): 0, ('T','G'): 0, ('T','C'): 0,
    ('G','A'): 0, ('G','T'): 0, ('G','G'): 0, ('G','C'): 0,
    ('C','A'): 0, ('C','T'): 0, ('C','G'): 0, ('C','C'): 0,
}
```

Again, we'll see the run-on effects later. We do, however, find issue colliding with the next value;

```
# also, creating an empty dictionary to store transition probabilities
# - probably upgrade using numpy
transition_prob_dict = {'A_A' : 0, 'A_T' : 0, 'A_G' : 0, 'A_C' : 0,
'T_A' : 0, 'T_T' : 0, 'T_G' : 0, 'T_C' : 0,
'G_A' : 0, 'G_T' : 0, 'G_G' : 0, 'G_C' : 0,
'C_A' : 0, 'C_T' : 0, 'C_G' : 0, 'C_C' : 0}
```

You haven't explained what makes these transition probabilities different, so the whole thing is really confusing. However, you only use this later on with `sub_probs` and co., so just move it down there:

```
transition_prob_dict = {'A_A' : 0, 'A_T' : 0, 'A_G' : 0, 'A_C' : 0,
'T_A' : 0, 'T_T' : 0, 'T_G' : 0, 'T_C' : 0,
'G_A' : 0, 'G_T' : 0, 'G_G' : 0, 'G_C' : 0,
'C_A' : 0, 'C_T' : 0, 'C_G' : 0, 'C_C' : 0}

# storing transition probability as dict
transition_prob_dict['A_A'] = sum_probs(transition_probs['A','A'], nucleotide_probs['A'])
transition_prob_dict['A_T'] = sum_probs(transition_probs['A','T'], nucleotide_probs['A'])
transition_prob_dict['A_G'] = sum_probs(transition_probs['A','G'], nucleotide_probs['A'])
transition_prob_dict['A_C'] = sum_probs(transition_probs['A','C'], nucleotide_probs['A'])

transition_prob_dict['T_A'] = sum_probs(transition_probs['T','A'], nucleotide_probs['T'])
transition_prob_dict['T_T'] = sum_probs(transition_probs['T','T'], nucleotide_probs['T'])
# ... etc ...
```

By this point you no longer want `transition_probs`, so you can just replace the name. Since everything is a data structure here, you can just implement a basic iteration.

```
for from_, nucleotide_prob in nucleotide_probs.items():
    for to in "ATGC":
        transition_probs[from_, to] = sum_probs(transition_probs[from_, to], nucleotide_prob)
```

The following code is now

```
# find possible configuration between "n" and "m".
hapb1a_hapb2a_transition = hap_b1_to_b2['a','a'][0][n], hap_b1_to_b2['a','a'][1][m]
hapb1b_hapb2b_transition = hap_b1_to_b2['b','b'][0][n], hap_b1_to_b2['b','b'][1][m]

hapb1a_hapb2b_transition = hap_b1_to_b2['a','b'][0][n], hap_b1_to_b2['a','b'][1][m]
hapb1b_hapb2a_transition = hap_b1_to_b2['b','a'][0][n], hap_b1_to_b2['b','a'][1][m]

# compute the products of transition probabilities on the for loop
prod_transition_probs['a','a'] *= transition_probs[hapb1a_hapb2a_transition]
prod_transition_probs['b','b'] *= transition_probs[hapb1b_hapb2b_transition]

prod_transition_probs['a','b'] *= transition_probs[hapb1a_hapb2b_transition]
prod_transition_probs['b','a'] *= transition_probs[hapb1b_hapb2a_transition]
```

which can also be transformed

```
for pair in prod_transition_probs:
    transition = hap_b1_to_b2[pair][0][n], hap_b1_to_b2[pair][1][m]
    prod_transition_probs[pair] *= transition_probs[transition]
```

Let us reverse a bit, to the `for x, y in sample_list`. We have

```
nucleotide_probs['A'] += v1[y][n].count('A')
nucleotide_probs['T'] += v1[y][n].count('T')
nucleotide_probs['G'] += v1[y][n].count('G')
nucleotide_probs['C'] += v1[y][n].count('C')
```

which is just

```
for nucleotide in 'ATGC':
    nucleotide_probs[nucleotide] += v1[y][n].count(nucleotide)
```

You have another redundant assignment, with a redundant comment, to remove.

```
hap_config = []  # create empty list
```

Inside you have

```
ziped_nuclb1b2 = [(x + '_' + y) for (x,y) in zip(nucl_b1, nucl_b2)]
hap_config = ziped_nuclb1b2

# move this counting function else where
transition_probs['A','A'] += (hap_config.count('A_A'))  # (v1[y][0].count('A'))/8
transition_probs['A','T'] += (hap_config.count('A_T'))
transition_probs['A','G'] += (hap_config.count('A_G'))
transition_probs['A','C'] += (hap_config.count('A_C'))

transition_probs['T','A'] += (hap_config.count('T_A'))  # (v1[y][0].count('A'))/8
transition_probs['T','T'] += (hap_config.count('T_T'))
transition_probs['T','G'] += (hap_config.count('T_G'))
transition_probs['T','C'] += (hap_config.count('T_C'))

transition_probs['G','A'] += (hap_config.count('G_A'))  # (v1[y][0].count('A'))/8
transition_probs['G','T'] += (hap_config.count('G_T'))
transition_probs['G','G'] += (hap_config.count('G_G'))
transition_probs['G','C'] += (hap_config.count('G_C'))

transition_probs['C','A'] += (hap_config.count('C_A'))
transition_probs['C','T'] += (hap_config.count('C_T'))
transition_probs['C','G'] += (hap_config.count('C_G'))
transition_probs['C','C'] += (hap_config.count('C_C'))
```

First, the `hap_config` variable seems rather strange to me. Secondly, more importantly, you write `x + '_' + y` when it would be nicer to deal in tuples to start with. Overall this whole thing can be compressed to

```
ziped_nuclb1b2 = list(zip(nucl_b1, nucl_b2))
for transition in transition_probs:
    transition_probs[transition] += ziped_nuclb1b2.count(transition)
```

and similar for the second run, though you should hoist the `zip` and use an `else` instead of an inverted `if`.

```
ziped_nuclb1b2 = list(zip(nucl_b1, nucl_b2))

if v1[x][n] == v2[x][m]:
    for transition in transition_probs:
        transition_probs[transition] += ziped_nuclb1b2.count(transition)
else:
    for transition in transition_probs:
        transition_probs[transition] += ziped_nuclb1b2.count(transition) / 2
```

Scrolling down a bit, because I've lost track of any semblance of order, we can replace

```
# step 02: sum of the product of the transition probabilities
transition_prob_sums['a','a'] += prod_transition_probs['a','a']
transition_prob_sums['b','b'] += prod_transition_probs['b','b']

transition_prob_sums['a','b'] += prod_transition_probs['a','b']
transition_prob_sums['b','a'] += prod_transition_probs['b','a']
```

with

```
for pair in transition_prob_sums:
    transition_prob_sums[pair] += prod_transition_probs[pair]
```

I'm going to leave this here for now, since I only have so much time to cover changes, though you can continue a lot of these cleanups in the same way. Other major untouched issues are around clearer high-level explanations, building the program out of separated functions, removing hardcoded paths, and moving to a matrix representation rather than a dictionary approach.

Comment: And I hope that I can some point in time. Also, I would like to bother you with other problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48737403/how-to-run-multiprocessing-and-or-multithreading-in-the-given-data-and-python-pr I am thinking if you can suggest me something on this. I don't mind learning but being formally a biologist, program related things happen slow for me. So, any explanations to help me learn faster is appreciative. I have looked into several parallelizing example on python but I cannot translate it to solve my problem.

Comment: Hi @veedrac : thank you for all the suggestions. As a beginner pythonist and also being informally self trained I am glad yo receive the formal check points and ideas from you. I am going to make suggested changes, making my program and explanation comprehensive. Btw, I am hoping someone can suggest me numpy/scipy implementation of my algorithm; if not I will wait couple of months to teach myself some numpy. Till then this should be enough

Comment: @everestial007 I probably won't have time for those, sorry.